# Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I'm writing an HOC in Reactjs. When I'm going to return class in `WithErrorHandler` HOC I get a warning in console said

> "Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you
>   return a Component instead of `<Component />` from render. Or maybe you
>   meant to call this function rather than return it." However, if I
>   remove class, warning will be gone.

I am going to add click handler for Modal to enable it to close. Also, I am going to get message from error which I have passed as an argument of second function for show in Modal.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from '../Modal'

const WithErrorHandler = WrappedComponent => ({ error, children }) => {

return(

  class extends Component {
state = {modalShow: false}   
modalToggle = ()=> {
this.setState(ModalShow: !!error.message)}
    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent>
          {error && <Modal type={error.messageType} message={error.message} />}
          {children}
        </WrappedComponent>
      );
      }
    }

)  
};

const DivWithErrorHandling = WithErrorHandler(({children}) => {
  return children
})

class App extends Component {
    state ={error: null}
    someMethode = ()=> {
      const sampleError = {//an object with message key}
      this.setState(error: sampleError)
    }
    Render(){
        return (
          <DivWithErrorHandling error={this.state.error} >
            <h1>Component</h1>
            <button onClick={this.someMethode}>
               Toggle Error
            </button>
          </DivWithErrorHandling>

        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also add an example on how you apply this HOC?

Comment: Hi could you try the following?
```
const WithErrorHandler = WrappedComponent => ({ error, children }) => {

return props =>(

return (
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props}>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your HOC is accepting actual component & returning a children function(wrapper component) which again returns a class component.

Instead of that your HOC should accept actual component & return a new wrapped component.

This should probably fix your issue.

```
const WithErrorHandler = WrappedComponent => ({ error, children }) => {
  return(
    <WrappedComponent>
      {error && <Modal type={error.messageType} message={error.message} />}
      {children}
    </WrappedComponent>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, as I said I am going to add close event method for Modal in anonymous class. because Modal has a method to close it. Yes it will work without anonymous class.

Comment: I know it will work without class. I am going to use some functionality in Modal. so, I should you class inside it.

Comment: @Xman2018 And as a convention, you might want to lower-case `withEventHandler` as capitalizing is for actual components while HoC is just a method returning a component.

Comment: @SungKim Thank you for your comment while did not solve my main issue.

Comment: This Modal component should serve so that all global messages to be handled in this HOC. There for having class in HOC is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

> HOC is a function that takes a component and returns a new component

Your code:

```
const WithErrorHandler 
    = WrappedComponent // takes a component
         => ({ error, children }) // takes some params
              => class ... // returns a new component
```

What you actually want:

```
const WithErrorHandler 
    = WrappedComponent // takes a component
         => class ... // returns a new component
            // inside the class use this.props.error, this.props.children, etc.
```

Another way (using a functional component):

```
const WithErrorHandler 
    = WrappedComponent // takes a component
         => ({ error, children }) =>  <WrappedComponent>...</WrappedComponent> // returns a new component
```